# Как сделать лучше regex'ом?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c#

Функция проверяет наличие цифр в строке:

```
bool HasDigits(string sample)
{
    bool has;

    foreach (char c in sample)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(c))
        {
            has = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return has;
}
```

Как сделать то же самое на регулярных выражениях? И нужно ли (по идее, должно быть меньше кода)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bool HasDigits(string sample) {
    return new Regex("\\d").IsMatch(sample);
}
```

Comment: Для паттернов лучше, всё же, использовать строку, в которой бэкслеши не раскрываются… Regex(@"\d")

Answer (score 7):

Игра не стоит свеч, право же.

Вы хотите забить гвоздь микроскопом… Вернее даже, наверное, многотонным прессом.

Регулярные выражения придуманы совсем не для этого. Столь простую обработку текста проще, читабельнее и **эффективнее** выполнить просто посимвольно.

Из Вашего кода можно убрать пару лишних строчек:

```
bool HasDigits(string sample)
{
    foreach (char c in sample)
    {
        if (char.IsNumber(c))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

P.S. Немного рассуждений о жизни: при написании программы главным приоритетом должна быть простота и читабельность. Лаконичность кода очень хороша, но стремление *сжать его как можно сильнее* обычно приводит к усложнению.

Да и короче уж точно не получится — у вас строки три уйдёт на то, чтобы подключить махину регулярных выражений, и ещё пара строк на работу с ними.

Comment: Немного добавлю. Если Вас интересуют регулярные выражения, есть про них одна замечательная книжка. Я, лично, с ними уже довольно долго вожусь, давно собирался книгу прочитать… А этим летом прочитал — прямо просветление снизошло! Называется Mastering Regular Expressions (http://regex.info/). Есть и русский перевод (но в нём опечатки!). Там найдёте про них абсолютно всё, и, что важно, там материал для читателя любого уровня — от человека, никогда про regexp не слышавшего, до профессионала.